# Back Button On IE8 Gets Disabled After X number of redirects from ASP to ASP.NET and back

Tags: .net, asp.net, internet-explorer, asp-classic

I have a website written in Classic ASP and ASP.NET, after a few redirects from Classic ASP  to ASP.NET the Back button in IE8 gets disabled.  The pages don't have no-cache set and I am not doing server.transfer.

Any ideas why the Back button gets disabled after X amount of redirects; also X is not always the same number?

After some more testing it happens when the page size is about 1.4 MB.

The sequence is ASP.NET page to ASP page and back to ASP.NET page after x it happens.  X can range from 1 and up.  There is a small ASP.NET out and ASP in to transfer the session information.

Comment: could you provide more details on the sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this to the registry will increase the IE Travel Log:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\TravelLog]
"MaxSize"=dword:ffffffff
```

Comment: I'm not able to find this TravelLog at the location that you have mentioned. please help.

Comment: thanks man. didn't realised you said to add and I thought there must be any existing key with same name!! App is working now.

Answer (score 2):

IE Travel log Bug if the page is large the history will be lost.

Link to List of IE bugs - http://www.enhanceie.com/ie/bugs.asp